# Gerar Tabela com Índice de grupo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, css

Como posso fazer uma Tabela que me mostre uma Linha no incio de cada Grupo numa tabela
Para me entender melhor estou colocando abaixo uma imagem de como eu preciso

Tabela Atual
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tabela Com Indice

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-primary table-vertical-center checkboxs js-table-sortable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="center" style="width: 10px;">Imóvel</th>
        <th style="width: 60px;">Inquilino</th>
        <th style="width: 60px;">Inicio</th>
        <th class="center"style="width: 50px;">Jan</th>
        <th class="center"style="width: 50px;">Fev</th>
        <th class="center"style="width: 50px;">Mar</th>
        <th class="center"style="width: 50px;">Abr</th>
        <th class="center"style="width: 50px;">Mai</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Jun</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Jul</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Ago</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Set</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Out</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Nov</th>
        <th class="center" style="width: 50px;">Dez</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?  

$busca = Sanitize::filter($_GET['consulta']);
$coluna = Sanitize::filter($_GET['coluna']);
$ano2 = Sanitize::filter($_GET['ano']); 
$data = Sanitize::filter($_GET['data']);
$status = Sanitize::filter($_GET['status']);
$consulta2 = Sanitize::filter($_GET['consulta']);

$filtro = "YEAR(f.vencimento) = $ano2 AND f.status = '$status' "; 

$sql = "SELECT f.*,i.*,n.*,q.*,

 q.nome AS nomecli,
 n.nome AS nomeimo,
 f.valor AS valor_fixado, 
 f.vencimento AS ven,
 f.status AS sta, 
 f.iptu AS iptuf, 
 f.rateio AS rateiof, 
 f.total AS totalf, 
 f.cb AS cbf FROM finan AS f

           LEFT JOIN imoveis AS i
           ON i.id_unidade = f.id_imovel
           LEFT JOIN nome_imoveis AS n
           ON n.id_imovel_principal = i.id_imovel
           LEFT JOIN inquilino AS q
           ON q.id_cli = i.id_inquilino
 where  YEAR(f.vencimento) = $ano group by f.id_imovel  ORDER by nomeimo ASC, unidade DESC";

 // Executa a consulta
 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 // ============================================
 // Começa a exibição dos resultados

 while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

 $id_finan = $linha['id_finan'];
 $nomeimo = $linha['nomeimo'];
 $nomecli = $linha['nomecli'];
 $unidade = $linha['unidade'];
 $id_imovel = $linha['id_unidade'];
 ?>   
<input type="hidden"  name="acao" value="up"  />   
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?echo $id?>" />
<tr class="selectable" >
        <td ><?echo $unidade?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $nomecli?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $start?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $jan?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $fev?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $mar?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $abr?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $mai?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $jun?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $jul?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $ago?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $set?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $out?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $nov?></td>
        <td class="important"><?echo $dez?></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <?}?>
```

Comment: Poste o código PHP também que está usando.

Comment: coloquei ele agora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução simples é agregar o nome dos imóveis em uma lista e conferir com [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) se a unidade em questão já tem uma linha título, assim:

```
// Cria uma lista para recolher os nomes dos imóveis
$imoveis = array();

while ($linha = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $id_finan = $linha['id_finan'];
    $nomeimo = $linha['nomeimo'];
    $nomecli = $linha['nomecli'];
    $unidade = $linha['unidade'];
    $id_imovel = $linha['id_unidade'];

    // Confere se o nome já está na lista, 
    // se não está, abra uma nova linha com o nome
    if ( ! in_array( $nomeimo, $imoveis ) ) {
        $imoveis[] = $nomeimo;
        ?>
        <tr><td colspan="14"><?php echo $nomeimo; ?></td></tr>
        <?php
    }

    // continua
}
```

Comment: Perfeito isso mesmo...