# Como eu faço pra exibir as areas de cada categoria?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa noite galera, estou precisando de uma ajudinha acabei me embolando aqui no PHP, é o seguinte, eu criei duas tabelas categoria e area, cada categoria tem várias áreas, cada área só pode ter uma categoria, o relacionamento eu consegui fazer, o problema é na hora de exibir, eu queria exibir assim:

```
Categoria1
   Area_dela
   Outra_area_dela...

Categoria2
   Area_dela
   Outra_area_dela...
```

E meu loop acabou ficando assim, tentei de tudo e o maximo que consegui exibir com o relacionamento foi assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Categoria **Em Geral** tem duas áreas, anuncios e atualizações, categoria **Outros** também...
*Nao consegui inserir o codigo aqui, tava cortando metade dele*

Código: http://pastebin.com/JVm0pHsC

```
<?php
include("inc/header.php");
$sqlCategorias = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT nomeCategoria, nomeArea FROM categoria INNER JOIN area ON categoria.idCategoria = area.idCategoria");

?>

<div class="container">
    <section class="categorias col-md-9">

        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlCategorias)):
                $nomeCategoria = $row['nomeCategoria'];
                $nomeArea = utf8_encode($row['nomeArea']);

        ?>
        <article>
            <h2><?php echo $nomeCategoria; ?></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $nomeArea;?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </article>
        <?php  
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </section>
    <aside class="widgets col-md-3">
        widgets
    </aside>
</div>


<?php
include("inc/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Veja se isso resolve: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162819/5213

Comment: desculpe, mas não entendi

Comment: Pelo que eu intendi, acho que seu problema ai é na modelagem do bd, isso pode estar gerando o problema que você esta enfrentando agora. Acredito que você terá que criar uma tabela intermediaria pra relacionar as áreas com as categorias, ai você passa id da categoria para essa tabela intermediária como chave estrangeira. De uma olhadinha [neste link](https://youtu.be/8fxKJWJcRTw) assista até a aula 16, quem sabe isso possa te passar alguma ideia de como resolver.

Comment: O problema da outra pergunta era igual ao seu: precisa de uma forma de iterar sobre os resultados de uma query de forma que os subitens fiquem abaixo do titulo de cada item. A solução se aplica, desde que você receba os dados do BD já na ordem correta.